# can we apply torricelli barrow theorem to $\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^x{f(x,t)}$

Tags: calculus

Will we get $f(x,x)$ when $f$ is integrable? 
The theorem applies to $\int f(t)$ but I am unsure about $f(x,t)$

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_0^x f(x,t) \, dt\implies \frac d{dx} \int_0^x f(x,t) \, dt=f(x,x)+\int_0^x\frac {\partial f(x,t)}{\partial x}\,dt$$

Comment: thanks. sorry but I did not understand your reply

Comment: nevermind. thanks to your explanation I spotted a typo in my question. so in general the answer is no? how did you get that formula? thanks again